# Метод для удаления (Spring + Postgresql)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jpa

Весь код я разбит на разные слои:

**Controller:**

```
package com.ex.admin.controllers;

import com.ex.admin.dto.EmployeeDTO;
import com.ex.admin.services.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.BasePathAwareController;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@BasePathAwareController
@RequestMapping("api/admin/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeServiceImpl employeeServiceImpl;

    @GetMapping(value = "/employees")
    public ResponseEntity<List<EmployeeDTO>> finAllEmployees() {
        return employeeServiceImpl.findAllEmployees();
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/delete")
    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO> deleteManyEmployees(@RequestBody List<String> codeList) {
        return employeeServiceImpl.deleteManyEmployees(codeList);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/delete/{code}")
    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("code") String employeeCode) {
        return employeeServiceImpl.deleteEmployee(employeeCode);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/create")
    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO> createEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeDTO employeeDTO) {
        return employeeServiceImpl.createNewEmployee(employeeDTO);
    }

    @PutMapping(value = "/edit")
    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO> editEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeDTO employeeDTO) {
        return employeeServiceImpl.editEmployee(employeeDTO);
    }
}
```

**Mapper**:

```
package com.ex.admin.dto.mappers;

import com.ex.admin.dto.EmployeeDTO;
import com.ex.admin.entity.Employee;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.Mappings;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface EmployeeMapper {
    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target="id", source="entity.id"),
            @Mapping(target="employeeName", source="entity.codeOfEmployee"),
            @Mapping(target="ruName", source="entity.nameRu"),
            @Mapping(target="kzName", source="entity.nameKk"),
            @Mapping(target="enName", source="entity.nameEn")
    })
    EmployeeDTO employeeToEmployeeDTO(Employee entity);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target="id", source="dto.id"),
            @Mapping(target="codeOfEmployee", source="dto.employeeName"),
            @Mapping(target="nameRu", source="dto.ruName"),
            @Mapping(target="nameKk", source="dto.kzName"),
            @Mapping(target="nameEn", source="dto.enName")
    })
    Employee employeeDTOtoEmployee(EmployeeDTO dto);
}
```

**Dto**:

```
package com.ex.admin.dto;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class EmployeeDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String employeeName;
    private String ruName;
    private String kzName;
    private String enName;

}
```

**Entity:**

```
package com.ex.admin.entity;


import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
@Data
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long  id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String  codeOfEmployee;

    @Column(name = "name_ru")
    private String  nameRu;

    @Column(name = "name_kk")
    private String  nameKk;

    @Column(name = "name_en")
    private String nameEn;

    @Column(name = "is_removed")
    private boolean  isRemoved;

    @Column(name = "create_time")
    private Date createTime;

    @Column(name = "edit_time")
    private Date editTime;

}
```

**Repository**:

```
package com.ex.admin.repository;

import com.ex.admin.entity.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee,Long > {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "SELECT * FROM employees where is_removed=false")
    Iterable<Employee> findAllExistingEmployees();

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Employee em SET em.isRemoved=:bool WHERE em.codeOfEmployee IN (:listOfCode)")
    Integer delManyEmployeesInRepo(@Param("bool") boolean bool, @Param("listOfCode") List<String> listOfCode);


    @Override
    Employee save(Employee entity);

    @Override
    Optional<Employee> findById(Long aLong);

    Employee findByCodeOfEmployee(String codeOfEmployee);

}
```

**Service:**

```
package com.ex.admin.services.impl;

import com.ex.admin.dto.EmployeeDTO;
import com.ex.admin.dto.mappers.EmployeeMapper;
import com.ex.admin.entity.Employee;
import com.ex.admin.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.*;

@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeMapper employeeMapper;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    public ResponseEntity<List<EmployeeDTO>> findAllEmployees() {
        Iterator<Employee> employeeIterator = employeeRepository.findAllExistingEmployees().iterator();
        List<EmployeeDTO> listEmployeeDTO = new ArrayList<>();

        while (employeeIterator.hasNext()) {
            listEmployeeDTO.add(employeeMapper.employeeToEmployeeDTO(employeeIterator.next()));
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(listEmployeeDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO> deleteManyEmployees(List<String> stringList) {
            //Реализация удаления всех сотрудников
    }


    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO> deleteEmployee(String employeeCode) {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findByCodeOfEmployee(employeeCode);
        employee.setRemoved(true);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(employeeMapper.employeeToEmployeeDTO(employeeRepository.save(employee)));
    }

    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO> createNewEmployee(EmployeeDTO employeeDTO) {
        //реализация Создания сотрудника
    }

    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO> editEmployee(EmployeeDTO employeeDTO) {

        employeeMapper.employeeDTOtoEmployee(employeeDTO);
        Optional<Employee> employeeOptional = employeeRepository.findById(employeeMapper.employeeDTOtoEmployee(employeeDTO).getId());
        Employee employee = employeeOptional.get();

        employee.setNameEn(employeeDTO.getEnName());
        employee.setCodeOfEmployee(employeeDTO.getEmployeeName());
        employee.setNameRu(employeeDTO.getRuName());
        employee.setNameKk(employeeDTO.getKzName());

        employeeDTO = employeeMapper.employeeToEmployeeDTO(employeeRepository.save(employee));

        return new ResponseEntity(employeeDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Не спрашивайте про архитектуру, я сам не знаю почему так, у нас нет лида или архитектора, поэтому как сделано, так сделано. Бекенд у меня связан с фронтендом(Vue.js).
В Сервисе есть методы, для удаления сотрудника и сотрудников.
Для сотрудника у меня получилось реализовать.

До сих пор не очень понимаю как это получилось.

```
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO> deleteEmployee(String employeeCode) {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findByCodeOfEmployee(employeeCode);
        employee.setRemoved(true);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(employeeMapper.employeeToEmployeeDTO(employeeRepository.save(employee)));
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на маленькую корзинку предназначенную для удаления 1 элемента работает. А вот если выбрать чекбоксом 3 элемента, вот так и нажать на большую корзину чтобы удалить несколько элементов, у меня не получается.:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно написать метод для удаления нескольких сотрудников, не очень понимаю(
Я в **Service** Отметил места где у меня не получается, специально стёр код потому что там тупо запутался и он не работал.

Answer (score 1):

- В цикле перебрать все пришедшие коды
- на каждый код, сходить в бд и посмотреть есть ли такие записи. Если есть удалить. Если нет то или проигнорировать или бросить ошибку клиенту.

  ```
  public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO> deleteManyEmployees(List<String> codesList){
       codesList.forEach(code-> {

          Optional< Employee > employee = employeeRepository.findByCode(code);

          if(employee.isPresent()) {
             employee.get().setRemoved(true);
          }

       });
  }
  ```

Репозиторий:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee,Long > {

   ...

   Optional<Employee> findByCode(String code);

   ... 
}
```

Я не знаю кто это делал, но применение аннотации `@Transactional` в репозитории вижу в первые и считаю это не корректным.

Я бы рекомендовал почитать что-то про спринг и т.д.

Comment: findByCode подчёркивает красным и еще этот же метод должен что-то возвращать, я что-то наподобие пытался, но так и не понял до конца

Comment: Читаю документацию и пытаюсь делать таски

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван ибо его нужно написать в Вашем репозитории.

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван обновил ответ.

Comment: А что он должен вернуть?Там же тип возвращаемого значения значит должен быть return и что-то

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван можете возвращать что-то, а можете и нет. Создайте лист и складывайте туда удаленные энтити.